# Gamma Distribution sample question

Tags: probability

Hello I am wondering about how to approach the following question;

Suppose we are told that the weight of each gum ball ( in centigram) is given by the gamma distribution function, with $\alpha=25$ and $\beta=2$.

We are wanting to know the probability that 100 gum balls will go over the limit of a standard package, of sixty grams.

My thought;

I know that form this type of distribution we have $E[X]= \alpha\beta=50$ Centigrams=$0.5g$

But then how would I go from here. Would I do something like

$P[100X \gt 60]=1-P[x \le 0.6]$ and then actually evaluate the distribution function? Or is there a much simpler way that I am just not saying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your notation, $E[X]= \alpha\beta$. Then I will assume this means that $\text{Var}[X] = \alpha\beta^2.$ If each weight $X_i$ is $iid$, then let $S = X_1+\dotsb+ X_{100}$. Then $E[X_i] = .5\text{ g}$, $\text{Var}[X_i] = 1 \text{ g}^2$, and
$$E[S] = 100E[X_1] = 50$$
and 
$$\text{Var}[S] = 100\text{Var}[X_1] = 100,$$
using independence.
Then the problem becomes the approximation
\begin{align*}
P(S >60) &= 1-P(S<60)\\
&= 1-P\left[Z<\frac{60-50}{\sqrt{100}}\right] \\
&=1-\Phi(1)\\
&= 0.1586553,
\end{align*}
where $Z$ is a standard normal distribution.

Comment: Thanks I thought I might have to use something like this

Comment: can you please help me . I am trying to do same problem but with diffirent numbers and it isnt coming out the same. I am trying it with same alpha and beta but with standard packing 52 instead of 60

Comment: I get 0.4207 but my teacher gets 0.0228

Comment: If you get the chance please let me know, thanks so much

Comment: Some asked the same thing I think [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1568655/please-help-checking-with-central-limit?noredirect=1#comment3193638_1568655). There seems to be a problem with the units.

Comment: Unlike the solution above, the other page has correct answers. (See the answer by @Brandon below.)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the problem reduces to evaluate a distribution, but you haven't settled it right.
Note that you don't have the same gum repeated 100 times. You have 100 of them, each with its own weight.
So you have 100 of iid gamma distributed random variables, each with parameters $\alpha=25$ and $\beta=2$.